IntelliJ IDEA not recognizing classes in multi-language Maven project
I have a maven project that contains two subprojects, one contains Clojure source, and the second contains Java source.
This is the top level POM file:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-clojure-test-2</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <modules>
        <module>clojure</module>
        <module>java</module>
    </modules>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>21</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>21</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

</project>

The Clojure project is set up to compile using clojure-maven-plugin, with the following POM file:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.example</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-clojure-test-2</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>clojure</artifactId>
    <packaging>clojure</packaging>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>21</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>21</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>


    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.theoryinpractise</groupId>
                <artifactId>clojure-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.8.3</version>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.clojure</groupId>
            <artifactId>clojure</artifactId>
            <version>1.11.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>

This project contains a single clojure source file, shown here:
(ns clojuretest.test
    (:gen-class
        :methods
        [[hello [] void]]))

(defn -hello [this] (println "running in clojure"))

The Java project is using IntelliJ's default settings, except that it has a dependency to the clojure project:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.example</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-clojure-test-2</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>java</artifactId>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>21</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>21</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.example</groupId>
            <artifactId>clojure</artifactId>
            <version>${project.parent.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>

This project also has a single source file:
package javatest;

public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println ("Java");
        new clojuretest.test().hello();
    }
}

When I compile this with Maven, everything works fine. The Java main function is able to be run, and the expected output is produced:
Java
running in clojure

However, the IntelliJ's java editor highlights new clojuretest.test().hello() as an error, and says that clojuretest is undefined. I presume it's searching for Java source files, not looking at the compiled .class files, to identify what is and is not a valid dependency.
How do I get it to recognize the classes built in a local dependency that aren't implemented in Java?
Things I've tried:

Enabling the "Delegate IDE build/run actions to Maven" checkbox
Invalidating caches
Adding the generated jar file in the clojure module as a library to the java module (by using right click -> add as library); this works, but isn't ideal because I will need to remove it and add it back in every time I increase the module's version number.

Really, I just need to find a way of telling IDEA to just use the contents of the module's jar file rather than trying to find source files in it.
Any ideas?

How have you added the Maven projects to IntelliJ? If it only knows about the parent project, it won't know what artifacts the child project produces. If you add the subproject as a submodule, it should know what to compile and where the build artifacts go.

I normally use the Clojure Deps/CLI utils to compile both Clojure and Java source as a single project. Would this be useful?

@amolloy - I created the subprojects using the "new module" option through IntelliJ, so it is aware of them. I can compile the project, the .class files go into target/classes appropriately, but IntelliJ ignores them, presumably because there's no corresponding .java file it can analyse.

@AlanThompson - compiling the code is no issue, the problem is simply that even once it's been compiled, the IntelliJ IDE tools don't seem to be aware of the classes generated by the Clojure compiler, so flag any reference to them as an error, even though compiling the project works fine.

Two suggested solutions to your problem:  (1) Get rid of the subprojects. They complicate things and I don't see a benefit.  (2) Get rid of Maven, and use either Leiningen or Deps/CLI to compile.
